# Recursive Rename of Files and Folders in a Given Directory with BATCH

Tags: batch-file, recursion

I'm trying to recursively rename all files and folders in a given directory to the uppercase version of whatever it is currently named. Lurking has gotten me this far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

pushd F:\

for %%f in (*) do (
   set "filename=%%~f"

   for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "filename=!filename:%%A=%%A!"
   )
    ren "%%f" "!filename!" >nul 2>&1
)
endlocal
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working recursively. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
for %%f in (*) do (
   set "filename=%%~f"
```

to

```
for /r %%f in (*) do (
   set "filename=%%~nxf"
```

Which traverses the entire tree and assigns simply the name and extension of `%%f` to `filename`.

Note that

```
for /r "F:\" %%f in (*) do (
```

will start the search at the quoted directoryname.

Comment: ok so the whole code, would look like

'@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /r F:\ %%f in (*) do (
   set "filename=%%~nxf"

   for %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
      set "filename=!filename:%%A=%%A!"
   )
    ren "%%f" "!filename!" >nul 2>&1
)
endlocal'